# Pressing backspace doesn't work in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have an problem in VSCode now.
When i try to press backspace it would do nothing instead of deleting the last character i typed. How do i fix this?

Comment: Are you using vim extensions?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just now, and it may be a keybinding issue. Hit CTRL+SHIFT+P and find keyboard shortcut preferences. Change any plain `backspace` keybind to whatever you wish it to be (I did `tab + backspace`). This may be because of an extension like Smart Backspace, not necessarily your fault. Sorry for being a year late to the party.

Comment: Update: Probably don't use `tab backspace` for the replacement, broke my tab key. But redoing the keybindings does work.

Answer (score -2):

you probably messed with your keybinding
try to reset your keybinding settings

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).